# How to concatenate a string, an integer and a sequence in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, concatenation, sequence

I have requirement where I need to concatenate a fixed string, a integer variable and a sequence. I am not sure how do I go about doing it in SQL Server 2012. I have been able to implement the same in PostgreSQL, but can anyone assist me in doing the same in SQL Server.

I have tried this code:

```
FORMAT((NEXT VALUE FOR dtr_seq),('DTR'++@lc_org_unit_id));
```

But it gives and error saying: 
    Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_dtr, Line 27
    Argument data type int is invalid for argument 2 of format function.

The code I used in PostgreSQL is like this:

```
SELECT ('DTR'||lc_org_unit_id||nextval('ccdb.dtr_seq');
```

The result that I am expecting is something like this:

```
DTR46361002
```

Please suggest me how do I go about implementing the same in SQL Server 2012

Comment: I think you want the [CONCAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh231515.aspx) function, not [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh213505.aspx) - `CONCAT('DTR', @lc_org_unit_id, (NEXT VALUE FOR dtr_seq));`

Comment: And if want to add number like 999 + nextval('ccdb.dtr_seq') THEN what is the syntax ? @GarethD

Comment: @KrunalPandya The syntax you have posted should work fine. Did you test it out? If you did, and it didn't work, you may need to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with more details about your problem.

Comment: yes, tested it its through syntax error but I find solution like (999::TEXT || nextval('ccdb.dtr_seq')::TEXT)::int Thank you for support @GarethD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 'DTR' + CAST((NEXT VALUE FOR dtr_seq)  AS VARCHAR(20)) 
       + CAST(@lc_org_unit_id  AS VARCHAR(20))
```

Comment: this is the old way of doing it, prior to SQL Server 2012, but still works like a charm, CONCAT function is only available in 2012 and later versions.

Comment: yeah.. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Thats fine then you can do it either way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function in 2012. SELECT CONCAT('DTR',lc_org_unit_id,nextval('ccdb.dtr_seq')). MSSQL 2012 will handle the conversions from char to int most of the time.